# exporting printed data on python

Tags: python, algorithm, file, export

My code is an mathematical algorithm that runs off the users inputs but there is one random factor within the algorithm. The user is given the option to export the data given from the algorithm but because of the random factor the exported data on the .txt file is different. Is there a way to get the printed data from shown on the GUI to be exported onto a file? Thanks.

```
import random
import os.path
def main ():
    print ("1.input numbers")
    print ("2.run formula")
    print ("3.export data")
    maininput = int(input("Enter:"))
    if maininput == 1:
        number ()
    if maininput == 2:
        formula ()
    if maininput == 3:
        export ()

def number ():
    number.one = int(input("first number"))
    number.two = int(input("second number"))
    number.repeat = int(input("times to be repeated"))
    main ()

def formula ():
    one = number.one
    two = number.two
    for x in range(1,number.repeat , +1):
        print ("sequence:",x)
        answer = one * two
        factor = random.uniform (0.8 ,0.5)
        final= answer * factor
        print ("before random:",round (answer))
        print ("after random:",round (final))
        one = final
    main ()

def export ():
    one = number.one
    two = number.two
    filename = input ("file name?")
    file = open (filename, "w")
    for x in range (1,number.repeat , +1):
        file.write ("sequence:" + str(x) + ":" + '\n')
        answer = number.one * number.two
        factor = random.uniform (0.8 ,0.5)
        final= answer * factor
        exanswer = round (answer)
        exfinal = round (final)
        file.write ("before random:" + str (exanswer) + '\n')
        file.write ("after random:" + str (exfinal) + '\n')
        number.one = exfinal
    file.close()
    main ()
```

main ()

this was as simplified as I could write the code and still provide an understanding of my intentions.

Comment: we'll need a little more to be able to help you out.. could you provide a simplified example of what you are having a problem with or the smallest section of your code needed to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I'll quickly write up a simplified version

Comment: you're able to print data to the GUI - couldn't you also write those values out to the file? `f.write(GUI_data)`, not sure what problem the random factor presents, should work the same

Comment: @Aaron I have included a simplified version of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your example, I have a few things to say that you should look into correcting, but first your main question:

#### why are the numbers different when I export vs. run the formula?:

The result you get will be different because you are re-calculating your results. getting a random number from the random library will be different each time, so when you re-calculate the answer to print it to a file, you generate a new different random factor, which changes the computation.

There are two relatively simple ways to solve this problem. A) save all the output and don't re-calculate, or B) force the random number generator to use the same sequence twice.

I'll let you figure out how to do the first one, but as for B) what you'll want to do is to make sure to give the random number generator the same "seed" before each time you want it to spit out the same sequence. In your example we only want the output to change if we change the numbers entered in the `number()` function, therefore that's when we will come up with our "random" seed. For non security based tasks it is generally considered "good enough" to take the current time for this purpose:

```
from time import time

def number ():
    number.one = int(input("first number"))
    number.two = int(input("second number"))
    number.repeat = int(input("times to be repeated"))
    number.seed = time() #save this seed for each time we need to compute
    main ()
```

Then to prepare the rng to output the same sequence, you need to give it this seed as a starting point before each of your `for` loops:

```
random.seed(number.seed)
```

This will ensure that each time you can call both `formula()` and `export()` and have the same mathematical computation take place.

#### Now for a brief rant (humor me)

In your example, you use `number.one`, `number.two` etc as global variables.. This in and of itself does work, but you can get into trouble very fast here. What you have done is assign attributes to your number function that store your variables in the object that contains the number function itself. Assigning random attributes to any old object will not work for everything, (if your variable is of type "int" you cannot do this etc..) and particularly pre-existing object types (in your case functions) may begin to act strangely if you accidentally modify the wrong attribute. There are two generally accepted "right" ways to use global variables that will hopefully prevent these issues.

The first is simply using the `global` keyword inside functions where you want to define global variables that will be used outside the scope of that function:

```
def number ():
    global one #make these variables accessable in global context
    global two
    global repeat
    global seed
    one = int(input("first number"))
    two = int(input("second number"))
    repeat = int(input("times to be repeated"))
    seed = time()
    main ()

def formula ():
    ONE = one #make local private copy of global variable 
    TWO = two 
    REPEAT = repeat 
    random.seed(seed)
    for x in range(1, REPEAT, +1):
        print ("sequence:",x)
        answer = ONE * TWO
        factor = random.uniform (0.8 ,0.5)
        final= answer * factor
        print ("before random:",round (answer))
        print ("after random:",round (final))
        ONE = final
    main ()
```

Another way to do global variables is actually similar to what you did with `number.xx` but in a much more controlled manner. What you can do is create an empty object as a container for all your global variables. to do this we will create a simple class that inherits from python's `object` class:

```
class globalcontext(object):
    pass #we don't actually need this class to do anything fancy
```

```
globvars = globalcontext()

def number ():
    globvars.one = int(input("first number"))
    globvars.two = int(input("second number"))
    globvars.repeat = int(input("times to be repeated"))
    globvars.seed = time()
    main ()

def formula ():
    ONE = globvars.one #make local private copy of global variable 
    TWO = globvars.two 
    REPEAT = globvars.repeat 
    random.seed(globvars.seed)
    for x in range(1, REPEAT, +1):
        print ("sequence:",x)
        answer = ONE * TWO
        factor = random.uniform (0.8 ,0.5)
        final= answer * factor
        print ("before random:",round (answer))
        print ("after random:",round (final))
        ONE = final
    main ()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've only just started to learn python and this is part of my first big project so any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: sorry for leaving a book on your post, but if you have any questions feel free to ask

Comment: Regarding the rant about global variables, if you were to assign something to `numbers.func_code`, it could really ruin your day... once you get into some pretty advanced python tomfoolery it's a very powerful thing to be able to modify function object attributes, but it's not something to be taken lightly, especially with user input as this could lead to malicious code execution if you weren't always the one to be providing the input.

Comment: @Josh if this helped you, I would appreciate either a vote or an accepted answer. (if you think it's trash you can downvote too I guess...)